# Pass value to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, action

I have a view that binds a id on the element just like this.

```
<a href="/listings/edit"><li onclick="edit(<%=listing.id%>);"" class="edit-listing"></li></a>
```

Clicking this will go to my listing/edit edit controller and edit view. I want to get the listing id passed by the href to my listing controller. Here's my controller:

```
def edit
    @listings = Listings.find_by(id: x)//x is my expected id
end
```

I tired changing my code into this.

```
<a href="/listings/edit?listingid=<%=listing.id%>"><li onclick="edit(<%=listing.id%>);"" class="edit-listing"></li></a>

def edit(listingid)
@listings = Listings.find_by(id: listingid)
end
```

I created the href as query string and pass it to the variable, but I got an error. wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

I also tried to putting it to a hidden value then pulling it from params on edit controller, but it doesn't seem to be available on the edit controller since it renders a new set of page. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of the query are found in the `params` hash

For example :

```
def edit
  @listings = Listings.find_by(id: params[:listingid])
end
```

[More on controllers here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Also, rails has neat helpers so you don't have to write tons of html :

```
<%= link_to edit_listing_path(listing) do %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

[Have a look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html)

Comment: I tried using params. But it doesn't seem to retrieve it when linking to another page.